# I want to read a file and also check a word whether the word is present in the file or not. If the word is present one of my method will return +1

Tags: java, string, comparison

This is my code. I want to read a file called "write.txt" and then once it reads. Compare it with a word, here I use "*target* variable(of string type) once the comparison is done inside the method called **findTarget** it will return **1** after the condition is true. I try to call the method but I keep getting an error. ***test.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
String testing = findTarget(target1, source1);***
                            ***^***
  ***symbol:   variable target1
  location: class test
1 error***
can someone correct my mistake. I am quite new to programming.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class test {

public static int findTarget( String target, String source ) 
{

int target_len = target.length();
int source_len = source.length();

int add = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < source_len; ++i) // i is an varialbe used to count upto 
source_len.
{
int j = 0; // take another variable to count loops        
    while(add == 0)
    {
        if( j >= target_len ) // count upto target length
        {
            break;
        }
        else if( target.charAt( j ) != source.charAt( i + j ) ) 
        {
            break;
        } 
        else 
        {
            ++j;
            if( j == target_len ) 
            {     
            add++; // this will return 1: true

            }
        }
    }
}
return add;
//System.out.println(""+add);
}
public static void main ( String ... args ) 
{
//String target = "for";
// function 1    
try
{
// read the file
File file = new File("write.txt"); //establising a file object
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   
//reading the files from the file object "file"

String target1; 
while ((target1 = br.readLine()) != null) //as long the condition is not null it will keep printing.
System.out.println(target1);

//target.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
  {
     System.out.println("file error!"); 
  }

String source1 = "Searching for a string within a string the hard way.";


// function 2

test ob = new test();

String testing = findTarget(target1, source1);


// end    
//System.out.println(findTarget(target, source));
System.out.println("the answer is: "+testing);


}

}
```

Comment: Check that the definition of target1 is in scope where it is being used. In other words within the same enclosing {} block of code.

Comment: I updated my answer for the latest change that you asked about... See the UPDATE part near the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `findTarget` is a class function.

So, where you have this:

```
test ob = new test();

String testing = findTarget(target1, source1);
```

...should be changed to call the function from a static context:

```
//test ob = new test();  not needed, the function is static

int testing = test.findTarget(target1, source1);
// also changed the testing type from String to int, as int IS findTarget's return type.
```

I don't have your file contents to give a trial run, but that should at least help get past the error.

=====
UPDATE:

You are close!

Inside main, change the code at your loop so that it looks like this:

```
String target1;
int testing = 0;  // move and initialize testing here

while ((target1 = br.readLine()) != null) //as long the condition is not null it will keep printing.
{
    //System.out.println(target1);

    testing += test.findTarget(target1, source1);
    //target1 = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println("answer is: "+testing);
```

Comment: I tried as you have instructed but I am still getting the same error! is there a way to attach my code along with my questions? I am new to StackOverflow.

Comment: No way to attach, but you CAN update the question and replace the code with the latest code that you have now.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally been able to solve my problem. but extending the functionalities. I want to increment the add by 1. but in my programming, it keeps giving me output as

> answer is: 1 answer is: 1

**instead I want my program to print not two 1's rather 1+1 = 2**

can someone fix this incrementing problem?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;


public class test {
    public static int findTarget(String target, String source) {

        int target_len = target.length();
        int source_len = source.length();

        int add = 0;

        // this function checks the character whether it is present.


        for (int i = 0; i < source_len; ++i) // i is a varialbe used to count upto source_len.
        {

            int j = 0; // take another variable to count loops

            while (add == 0) 
            {
                if (j >= target_len) // count upto target length
                {
                    break;
                } 
                else if (target.charAt(j) != source.charAt(i + j)) 
                {
                    break;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    ++j;
                    if (j == target_len) 
                    {

                        add++; // this will return 1: true

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return add;
        //System.out.println(""+add);

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

    //String target = "for";
    // function 1
        try {
            // read the file
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter your review: ");
            String source1 = sc.nextLine();

            //String source1 = "Searching for a string within a string the hard way.";
            File file = new File("write.txt"); //establising a file object
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); //reading the files from the file object "file"

            String target1;
            while ((target1 = br.readLine()) != null) //as long the condition is not null it will keep printing.
            {
                //System.out.println(target1);


                int testing = test.findTarget(target1, source1);
                System.out.println("answer is: "+testing);
                //target1 = br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("file error!");
        }
    }
}
```